# What's the implementation of other program create second domain of a domain?

Tags: domain, subdomain

How can a program create second level even third level domains ?

we know many services on Internet(Such as `ngrok`), if we buy its service, it will generate random second level domain to us.

```
randomtext.example.com
```

as we know, we create a second level domain in GoDaddy manually, but how can the service program create it ?

is Domain provider have any APIs for domain management?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating these additional domains is just a matter of creating new DNS records.  There's no single solution for how this is accomplished and the task may not involve your domain registrar at all.  DNS is handled separately from domain registration on a technical level, though registrars will typically handle this service for you.

Many DNS providers likely [provide](https://developer.godaddy.com/doc/endpoint/domains#/v1/recordAdd) some [sort](https://developers.linode.com/api/v4/domains-domain-id-records-record-id) of [API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/dns/) that [one](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API-actions-by-function.html#API-actions-by-function-dns) could use to dynamically modify DNS records.  If this is an important feature for you then you'll need to determine if your current DNS provider provides such a service or move your DNS hosting to another service by updating your domain's nameserver settings with your registrar.

For those that need to make dns changes often and easily they might instead decide to host their own DNS servers.  This would allow them the most control over how their domain's DNS is configured and they can implement which ever solution is best for them.  For example, they might choose to configure [BIND with a MySQL back end](http://mysql-bind.sourceforge.net/) so that updating their DNS is as simple as updating their database records.